# wordpress how to query wp_options table

Tags: plugin-development, options

I need to make an SQL call to find all records in wp_options matching a select statement. How do I query the table?

My script already has these resources called...

```
require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
require_once('../../../wp-admin/includes/file.php');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of database querying is handled by global [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object. So when you load WP core you have acess to it and all its methods for queries.